# Nvidia driver for not detected (GT740M)

Tags: nvidia

I wanted to install the NVIDIA driver but it fails and no any driver supports GT-740M. How can I fix it?

```
mehman@HP:~$ lspci -nnk | grep VGA -A1
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [103c:1964]
```

As you see no NVIDIA detected.

Thank you beforehand

Comment: I use Ubuntu 17.04 with Gnome environment

Answer (score 0):

According to the Nvidia web site, there are no Linux drivers for this card.

Assuming that the PCI card is properly installed (it's always a good idea to remove and reinstall any hardware that is not recognized), type:

lspci | grep Graphics

The 700M family of graphics cards has been around for a while and should be supported by Ubuntu by now.  If you have your monitor plugged in to the PCI graphics card connector, the card is obviously working.  You may have to suffer with a reduced Nvidia feature set though.

Comment: `mehman@HP:~$ lspci | grep Graphics
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
mehman@HP:~$`

Here is result. I use Laptop and it has GT 740M and Intel VGA. I know that my NVIDIA card works. Becasue when I run Blender, GPU render is available but it's not selectable and renders via GPU.

Comment: If applications can utilize the GPU as a computing resource, then the kernel is seeing the GT-740M.  I think that's what you're saying it's doing.  If your monitor works when it's plugged in to the 740M and if the GPU is available to other applications that may be as good as it gets since Nvidia has chosen to not make a Linux driver available for your card.

Comment: When I switch to GT740M I can not launch Blender. I need to restart PC and when i re-enter the NVIDIA settings it automatically detects INTEL VGA instead of NVIDIA

Comment: As I said in my answer, since there are no drivers available you can expect limited functionality at best.  Still not clear if you have an integrated VGA port AND a PCI port(s).  Either way, if your monitor works when plugged in to the PCI card port, it's quite possible for resource distribution capabilities offloading work to the GPU may just not be there in Ubuntu.